# What would prevent a custom role from viewing posts (both standard and custom)?

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I am using a custom role (from the premium plugin [wp-client](http://wp-client.com/)) but for some reason it can't view posts or pages of any kind. WordPress shows the correct post count but only shows the message "No posts found".

[image: Post count shows posts exist but they aren't displayed...]

Strangely, it is possible to edit the post content if you have the right edit url (i.e. example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=XXX&action=edit).

I have tried using multiple capability managers to assign the correct permission levels but this has no effect. This behaviour is identical across posts, pages and custom posts. Other custom roles made by the plugin can view everything normally.

What could cause this?

Comment: This depends on the capabilities assigned to the role by the plugin. Which Plugins are we talking about?

Comment: The plugin I'm working with is a premium membership plugin - [wp-client](http://wp-client.com/).It creates several custom roles including an Admin Role (no problems) and a Manager Role (big no-no on viewing posts).

I'll update the question to clarify this.

Comment: Especially if it is a premium plugin I suppose you contact support as that is what you probably payed for in the first place. With non-public code it is difficult to debug.

Comment: I have asked their support team and I'm still waiting on a response. For now I'm just wondering if there is anything simple I could have missed at my end. Is there anything in the normal WordPress functionality that would prevent a user role from viewing posts in the "All Posts" screen but nothing else?

Comment: There are a lot of capabilities in WordPress. It depends on what the role is set to. Have a look at [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved by an update to the plugin by the developers after prompting by support tickets.

The WP-Client plugin is currently at v3.5.1